# Try to return in ternary expression

Tags: ios, swift, ternary

I have a Swift application.

I'm getting the error `Expected expression after '?' in ternary expression` from Xcode compiler

in

```
private func getContentPre(highlight: Highlight) -> String!

    {
        highlight.contentPre.count == 0 ? return ">" : return highlight.contentPre
    }
```

Apple docs says:

[image]

why isn't it possible to `return` in ternary expression like using if statement?

Comment: return highlight.contentPre.count == 0 ? if true : if false

Comment: Please read [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID71)

Comment: `return highlight.contentPre.count == 0 ? ">" : highlight.contentPre`, maybe...? or just write the evaluation out: `if highlight.contentPre.count == 0 { return ">" } else { return highlight.contentPre }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should re-write your function like this. This will evaluate the count of the `contentPre` variable and return the appropriate response.

```
private func getContentPre(highlight: Highlight) -> String! {
    return highlight.contentPre.count == 0 ? ">" :  highlight.contentPre
}
```

However as it would appear that `contentPre` would be a `String` you should use `.isEmpty` as it is more performant that checking the length of a `String`

```
private func getContentPre(highlight: Highlight) -> String! {
    return highlight.contentPre.isEmpty ? ">" :  highlight.contentPre
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`return` does not return anything - I mean, to the function what calls it. Ternary operator's parameters must be expressions.